# C++ printing linked list , segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

```
void Print(Node *head)
{

    if (head = NULL)
    {
        cout << "NULL";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
        while (head->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << head->data << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
        cout << "NULL";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `if (head = NULL)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that the line

```
if ( head = NULL )
```

is an error in transcribing your code, and that your working code uses

```
if ( head == NULL )
```

The real error I see is that you are using

```
    cout << head->data << endl;
    head = head->next;
    while (head->next != NULL)  // This line is not good
    {
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
```

That line will always be a problem. At some point, `head` will be equal to `NULL` and you will try to access the `NULL` pointer.

Change that block of code to:

```
while (head != NULL)
{
    cout << head->data << endl;
    head = head->next;
}
cout << "NULL";
```

In fact, the entire function can be:

```
void Print(Node* head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you assign NULL to head

`if (head = NULL)` must be `if (head == NULL)`